# Authentication expiry dates and single login at a time

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I work on an angular web-app with a nodeJS backend. I want to implement the two following features:

1. User expiry dates: I want to be able to grand each user a period of time in which he can use my app (a trial-period). After this period of time has expired, the user will be logged-out and will not be able to log-in again.
2. Single user at a time: I want each user to be logged just once. If a user will log-in on a second device, his first device will be logged-out.

Can you please advice how can I achieve such functionality?
Should I use anything like Firebase to help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use req.session.cookie.expires after installing the express-session package to handle the time of authentication

https://github.com/expressjs/session
or
https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session

2. check this:

[Only allow signing in from one device at a time in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028920/only-allow-signing-in-from-one-device-at-a-time-in-nodejs)